# What are the hidden commands/controls for Cat Life: ChatChat?

Tags: cat-life-chatchat

There are no listed controls in the instructions, but I know about the arrow keys and the `/nap` and `/me` commands. Are there any other commands and controls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few more commands, including `/purr`, `/meow`, and `/screech`.

You also get a different set of commands as a dog. To become a dog,

> catch a mouse and bring it to the Dog Altar, accessible through the top-right corner of the Alley, East Side.

Once you've become a dog, you gain access to `/howl`, `/bark`, and `/pant`.

However, as a dog, you lose the ability to chat, instead sending a random amount of `woof`s. The cat commands `/purr`, `/meow`, and `/screech` are also lost to you, and you get a different sound effect when using `/nap`.

You can return to being a cat by

> catching another mouse and bringing it to the doormat, where you spawn.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with schism but you can also put /me then your message to remove the : and make the message the color your chat is also to become a dog you can also get caught a different dog and to be a cat you can catch a different cat in your game (I've played Chatchat)